# Parallel.ForEach gives different results each time

Tags: vb.net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel.foreach

Please help me to convert following loop to Parallel loop. I tried using Parallel.ForEach and ConcurrentBag instead of HashSet, but the wied thing is that "Matched" returns every time different results.

I can't figure it out... Is it because of Thread Safety issues?

Keywords list contains about 500 unique strings, each 1-3 words in lenght.

Items contains about 10000 items.

Original code:

```
    Dim Items As IEnumerable(Of Item) = Db.Items.GetAll

    Dim Keywords As HashSet(Of String) 
    Dim Matched As HashSet(Of Item)

    For Each Item In Items

        For Each Keyword In Keywords

            If Regex.IsMatch(Headline, String.Format("\b{0}\b", Keyword), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant) Then 
                If Not Matched.Contains(Item) Then
                    Matched.Add(Item)
                End If

            End If

        Next

    Next
```

Attempt to convert it to

```
Dim Items As IEnumerable(Of Item) = Db.Items.GetAll

Dim Keywords As HashSet(Of String) 
Dim Matched As Concurrent.ConcurrentBag(Of Item)

Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach(Of Item)(Items, Sub(Item)
    For Each Keyword In Keywords
        If Regex.IsMatch(Item.Title, String.Format("\b{0}\b", Keyword), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant) Then
            If Not Matched.Contains(Item) Then
            Matched.Add(Item)
            End If
       Continue For
      End If
   Next
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your code certainly isn't thread-safe. Using thread-safe collections won't make your code automatically thread-safe, you still need to use them correctly.

Your problem is that after `Contains()` finishes but before `Add()` is called on one thread, `Add()` can be called on another thread (and the same can possibly also happen *while* `Contains()` executes).

What you need to do is to:

1. Use locking (this means you won't need to use a thread safe collection anymore); or
2. Use something like `ConcurrentHashSet`. There is no such class in .Net, but you can use `ConcurrentDictionary` instead (even if it doesn't fit your needs exactly). Instead of your call to `Contains()` and then `Add()`, you could do `Matched.TryAdd(Item, True)`, where `True` is there just because `ConcurrentDictionary` needs some value.

Comment: I found these two samples with another approach. Tired to change, but could not make it work with my collections and objects instead of integes like in these samples. 

Svick, do you think these will work in my case?

http://technet.microsoft.com/subscriptions/dd460699.aspx 
http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/ParallelClass.html